# Python scraping with beautifulsoup cannot scrape properly some lines of data

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-3.8

I am exploring web scraping in python. I have the following snippet but the problem with this code is that some lines of data being extracted is not correct. What could be the problem of this snippet?

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://bscscan.com/txsinternal?ps=100&zero=false&valid=all'
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req, timeout=10).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')

for row in rows[1:]:
    ttype = (row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:])
    amt = (row.find_all('td')[7].text[0:])
    transamt = str(amt)
    print()
    print ("this is bnbval: ", transamt)
    print ("transactiontype: ", ttype)
```

Sample output:

```
trans amt:   Binance: WBNB Token #- wrong data being extracted
transtype:  0x2de500a9a2d01c1d0a0b84341340f92ac0e2e33b9079ef04d2a5be88a4a633d4 #- wrong data being extracted

trans amt:  1 BNB
transtype:  call

trans amt:  1 BNB
transtype:  call

this is bnbval:   Binance: WBNB Token #- wrong data being extracted
transactiontype: 0x1cc224ba17182f8a4a1309cb2aa8fe4d19de51c650c6718e4febe07a51387dce #- wrong data being extracted

trans amt:  1 BNB
transtype:  call
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. But there is a problem with the data on the page.

Some rows are 7 column rows - one that you're expecting, and some rows are 9 column rows. Those that are 9 column rows give you wrong data.

You can just go to the page and inspect elements to see the issue.

I can suggest that you use the last element `[-1]` instead of `[7]`. But you need to have some kind of if check for 3rd column

Comment: Thank you. With your idea, I am able to find a workaround. Its working already as what I wanted.